# Python Check String in Column to perform an equation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df that looks like below and I am trying to create a new column called `df['Seat_AVAIL']` based on the `plan` column and the `Mem_Count` column.

Essentially:

IF `df['Plan']` = (`'LUX'` or `'Premium'`) then, calculate `df['Seat_AVAIL']` by doing (10+(*mem_count val*-1)*5),

elif `df['Plan']` =  `'Limited'` then, calculate `df['Seat_AVAIL']` (5+(*mem_count val*-1)*2) to calculate `Mem_count`

else  `df['PLAN']` = `'Free'` then `df['Seat_AVAIL']` should be null.

DATAFRAME:

```
ID    Guest_COUNT   Mem_COUNT   Plan
8472    82            20     Free 
2426    67            10     Premium
2299    55            21     LUX
3787    48            52     LIMITED
2553    41            12     Free 
8660    39            16     Premium
```

**Desired Output Example w/ Calc for Seat_AVAIL**

```
ID    Guest_COUNT   Mem_COUNT   Seat_AVAIL    Plan
8472    82            20          NULL             Free 
2426    67            10          50               Premium
2299    55            21         110               LUX
3787    48            6           15               LIMITED
2553    41            12         NULL              Free 
8660    39            8           45               Premium
```

I tried doing something similar directly in google sheets using an ifs statement but was having errors and figured python might have a quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with specified masks and outputs, if no match any mask values is return same column:

```
m1 = df['Plan'].isin(['LUX', 'Premium'])
m2 = df['Plan'] == 'Limited'
m3 = df['Plan'] == 'Free'

s1 = 10+(df['Mem_COUNT']-1)*5
s2 = 5+(df['Mem_COUNT']-1)*2

df['Seat_AVAIL'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [s1, s2, np.nan], default=df['Mem_COUNT'])

print (df)
     ID  Guest_COUNT  Mem_COUNT     Plan  Seat_AVAIL
0  8472           82         20     Free         NaN
1  2426           67         10  Premium        55.0
2  2299           55         21      LUX       110.0
3  3787           48         52  LIMITED        52.0 <- no match
4  2553           41         12     Free         NaN
5  8660           39         16  Premium        85.0
```

Or if need match only first 2 masks and if no match always return `NaN`:

```
df['Seat_AVAIL'] = np.select([m1, m2], [s1, s2], default=np.nan)

print (df)
     ID  Guest_COUNT  Mem_COUNT     Plan  Seat_AVAIL
0  8472           82         20     Free         NaN
1  2426           67         10  Premium        55.0
2  2299           55         21      LUX       110.0
3  3787           48         52  LIMITED         NaN <- no match
4  2553           41         12     Free         NaN
5  8660           39         16  Premium        85.0
```